# Sumar existencias de dos tablas, columnas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buen dia, a ver si pueden ayudarme con esta consulta.

El resultado esperado sería así por un rango de fechas y por proveedor:

```
clave           descripcion             precio      cantidadComprada  cantidadVendida
7503023836142   VUALA CHOCOLATE 60 G    12.039000   30.0000           5.0000
7501000646975   VUALA CAJETA 70G        12.039000   24.0000           4.0000
7501055330461   VALLE FRUT 2LT          20.968000   40.0000           5.0000
```

Explicacion:
Tengo 6 tablas que se conforman por

```
articulo(art_id, descripcion), 
compra(com_id, fecha, provedor_id), 
detallecompra(com_id, art_id, cantidadComprada), 
proveedor(proveedor_id, nombre), 
venta(ven_id, fecha), 
detalleventa(ven_id, art_id, cantidadVendida)
```

Mi codigo que me arroja resultados pero no son correctos en compra pero en venta si:

```
SELECT a.clave, a.descripcion, a.precio1, SUM(dc.cantidad) as cantidadComprada, SUM(dv.cantidad) as cantidadVendida, c.fecha, v.fecha FROM sicar.articulo a
INNER JOIN sicar.detallec dc ON dc.art_id=a.art_id
INNER JOIN sicar.compra c ON c.com_id=dc.com_id
INNER JOIN sicar.proveedor p ON p.pro_id=c.pro_id
INNER JOIN sicar.detallev dv ON dv.art_id=a.art_id
INNER JOIN sicar.venta v ON v.ven_id=dv.ven_id
WHERE 
c.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59' AND 
v.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59' AND
p.nombre LIKE '%COCA COLA%' 
group by a.art_id
order by a.descripcion DESC;
```

es mysql, el detalle es que solo funciona en la columna de venta la sumatoria. Pero no funciona en la columna de compra al sumar cantidadades. Es por eso que se hace el group by, por si se vuelve a comprar el mismo producto en el rango de fechas seleccionadas

Saludos, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Por favor, detalla tu problema. Acabas de decir, Quiero esto, tengo esto y no funciona, ayúdenme.

Comment: Además, esto es mysql, mysqli o sql ? Pusiste 3 etiquetas

Comment: Hola es mysql, perdona. El detalle es que solo funciona en la columna de venta la sumatoria. Pero no funciona en la columna de compra al sumar cantidadades. Es por eso que se hace el group by, por si se vuelve a comprar el mismo producto en el rango de fechas seleccionadas.

Comment: Entonces aclara eso para que la gente pueda responderte, muestra que tienes, que problema tienes, y que quieres lograr. Para que quede claro al lector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noté diferencias entres los nombres de columnas en tu modelo de datos y tu query (ej: en la tabla compra la columna se llama provedor_id y en tu query utilizas prod_id).

Para poder sumar cantidades vendidas y compradas lo tienes que hacer en dos subqueries separadas, porque sino en uno de los dos casos seguramente la sumatoria va a ser incorrecta (si el número de ventas en el que aparece el artículo es distinto del número de compras en el que aparece). La forma mas facil de ver porque ocurre esto es haciendo una query vinculando articulos compras y ventas de un solo articulo que aparezca en una sola compra y en mas de una venta sin agrupar.

También ten en cuenta que al hacer un INNER JOIN, si el artículo nunca fue vendido tampoco te va a aparecer en el resultado.

He reecho la query debido a que al utilizar dos subqueries (compra y venta) vinculadas con un LEFT JOIN, si el artículo fue comprado fuera del rango de fechas pero vendido dentro del mismo, no iba a aparecer en el resultado.

La query:

He utilizado dos subqueries:

- La primera para listar las compras de los artículos comprados a un determinado proveedor entre un rango de fechas.
- La segunda para listar las ventas de los artículos comprados alguna vez a un determinado proveedor, entre un rango de fechas de venta. Podrías restringir si quisieras las fechas en que fue comprado dicho artículo a dicho proveedor.

Luego hago un UNION ALL de ambos resultados, vinculo con artículo (INNER JOIN), agrupo por artículo y sumo las cantidades vendidas y compradas.

```
SELECT 
    a.art_id,
    a.descripcion, 
    a.precio1, 
    SUM(sq.cantidadComprada) AS cantidadComprada,
    SUM(sq.cantidadVendida) AS cantidadVendida
    
FROM (

    SELECT dc.art_id, 
           dc.cantidad AS cantidadComprada,
           0 AS cantidadVendida

    FROM detallecompra dc
    INNER JOIN compra c ON c.com_id = dc.com_id
    INNER JOIN proveedor p ON p.proveedor_id = c.proveedor_id

    WHERE 
           c.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59'
           AND p.nombre LIKE '%COCA COLA%' 


    UNION ALL
    

    SELECT dv.art_id, 
           0 AS cantidadComprada,
           dv.cantidad AS cantidadVendida

    FROM detalleventa dv
    INNER JOIN venta v ON v.ven_id = dv.ven_id

    WHERE 
           v.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59' 
           AND dv.art_id IN (
               SELECT dc.art_id
               FROM detallecompra dc
               INNER JOIN compra c ON c.com_id = dc.com_id
               INNER JOIN proveedor p ON p.proveedor_id = c.proveedor_id
               WHERE p.nombre LIKE '%COCA COLA%' 
               GROUP BY dc.art_id)
   ) AS sq
    
INNER JOIN articulo a ON sq.art_id = a.art_id

GROUP BY a.art_id, a.descripcion, a.precio1

ORDER BY a.descripcion;
```

Comment: Hola nachospiu! Sirvió bastante, no me arrojaba la cantidadVendida correctamente pero en el 'q2' solo elimine lo que tiene que ver con compras y proveedor. Así ya me arroja bien el resultado. el codigo correcto lo dejo en un comentario adicional. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Hola @CesarOliverJiménez! Si tienes razón, terminé incurriendo en el mismo error que intentaba evitar. Modifiqué la respuesta ya que la query no era correcta, si un artículo fue comprado fuera del rengo de fecha pero vendido dentro del mismo, no aparecía en el resultado. No ovlides seleccionar la respuesta que mejor conteste tu pregunta, así la misma queda cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

he tenido problemas similares con la clausula SUM pero ha sido por que debe ponerse en el group by todas las otras columnas asi:

```
GROUP BY a.clave, a.descripcion, a.precio1, c.fecha, v.fecha
```

Intenta con eso y me cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

ya se logró resolver! Se mejoró el query que nos comparte nachospiu y queda de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT q1.clave,
       q1.art_id, 
       q1.descripcion, 
       q1.precio1, 
       q1.cantidadComprada,
       q2.cantidadVendida
       
FROM (
    SELECT a.art_id, 
           a.descripcion, 
           a.precio1, 
           SUM(dc.cantidad) as cantidadComprada,
           a.clave
       
    FROM articulo a
    INNER JOIN detallec dc ON dc.art_id = a.art_id
    INNER JOIN compra c ON c.com_id = dc.com_id
    INNER JOIN proveedor p ON p.pro_id = c.pro_id

    WHERE 
          c.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59' AND 
          p.nombre LIKE '%SABRITAS%' 
          
    group by a.art_id, a.descripcion, a.precio1) AS q1

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a.art_id, 
           a.descripcion, 
           a.precio1, 
           SUM(dv.cantidad) as cantidadVendida
       
    FROM articulo a
    INNER JOIN detallev dv ON dv.art_id = a.art_id
    INNER JOIN venta v ON v.ven_id = dv.ven_id

    WHERE 
          v.fecha BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' and '2021-06-08 23:59:59' 
          
    group by a.art_id, a.descripcion, a.precio1) AS q2 ON q1.art_id = q2.art_id

ORDER BY q1.descripcion;
```